# How send email with "execute as user"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, senddbmail

I need that all my system users can send email from the DB.
not to assign everyone the role in the msdb database I created one login/user "send_mail", and grant permission on msdb db, specifically DatabaseMailUserRole.

I need that all my users send email execute a store procedure that within execute the statement execute as user='send_mail" before of msdb..sp_send_db_mail.

The user send_mail have db_owner, and the DatabaseMailUserRole, but can't send email.

The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: This may sound crazy, but maybe the user calling the stored procedure shouldn't be the one with permissions to actually send the e-mail. Insert the e-mail into a queue table and let a background process send the e-mails.

Comment: thanks Aaron! i think that is really crazy jajaja. Your solution makes much more sense

Comment: I'm doing similar thing recently, creating a procedure with EXECUTE AS, switch to user to run IS_MEMBER() check and revert back to sysadmin to call a job (in your case, to send an email) and maybe pass in parameters